# Determining if a string macro variable does not exist in a column of a dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a string macro variable `%let string=abc` and a dataset column that contains values `def` `ghi`.

How do I use datastep to run `&string.` through the entire column to create an indicator macro variable to show that `abc` does not exist in the column?

Comment: ALL macro variables are strings. You don't "run" macro variables, you just include them in your code. If your column only contains `def` and `ghi`, how could it contains `abc`? You win the Nobel Price for obscurity.

Comment: Its okay, it did not seem "obscure" for @shaun_m to understand my need.

Comment: Lame excuse for polluting our knowledge base with chat-quality language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `call symput()` to create a macro variable in a data step.

The code below creates a macro variable which has value 0 if the string is not found in the data, and value 1 if the string is found:

```
* create example data;
data have;
    input var1 $;
    datalines;
def
ghi
;
run;

%let string=abc;

* data step to create variable STRING_CHECK which equals 1 if HAVE contains 'abc', and equals 0 otherwise;
data _null_;
    set have (keep=var1) end=last_obs;
    retain flag 0;
    if var1 = "&string" then flag=1;
    * at end of data set, create the required macro variable;
    if last_obs then call symput('string_check',left(flag));
run;

%put &=string_check;
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you @shaun_m! Learnt something new with `end=last_obs`.